# load more using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div having 100 results like.

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="sub">This is a test 1</div></br>
    <div class="sub">This is a test 2</div></br>
    <div class="sub">This is a test 3</div></br>
    .
    .
    .
     <div class="sub">This is a test 1oo</div></br>
 </div>
```

At a time I am showing 10 results how can I add another 10 results on clicking add more button and so on.

Comment: The trick is organizing your results. Where are you getting them from?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$('#main').append('[html for more divs]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could copy your existing content:

```
$('#show_more').click(function(){
  $('#main').append($('#main').html());
});
```

Hope this helps